# Access other variables within scales::transformation for ggplot faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, transformation, r-sf

I have a dataframe along the lines of:

```
library(tidyverse); library(sf); library(ggplot2)
sfc <- tribble(~analyte, ~value, ~guideline, ~lat, ~long,
              "pH",     4,      5,          21,   52,
              "pH",     7,      5,          22,   53,
              "EC",     50,     100,        21,   52,
              "EC",     200,    100,        22,   53) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4326)
```

Where I have the name of some analytical test in 'analyte', the result of the test in 'value', a guideline value that result should be below in 'guideline' and the location of the sampling point in lat and long. Each analyte has only a single guideline.

I want to make a faceted set of maps, where each facet is a different analyte, with the values shown as different sized points.

```
ggplot(sfc) +
  geom_sf(aes(size = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~analyte)
```

However, what I want is for the size scale to vary for each facet so that it goes something like:

```
value         size
0         ->  0 px
guideline ->  5 px
max(value)->  (max(value)/guideline)*5) px
```

With the size scaling different for each facet/analyte, but with a value of 0 always set to a size of 0px and a value equal to that analyte's guideline value always being set as 5px.

So, I think I need to use trans_new() to create a new transformation, but I'm struggling to figure out how I can let the function know what that facet's analyte name is, so that it can look up the appropriate guideline value.

Any ideas, would be appreciated.

**Clarification edit:** Looking at the plot, I would like to be able to see *both* the actual magnitude of the value (eg. pH around 10) and also the amount that the value is larger or smaller than the guideline value (eg. pH value of 10 is around twice the guideline value of 5). So ideally I would like a legend for each facet where the size of each dot shows the relative size of the measured value compared to the guideline value, but actual measured values (rather than percent of guideline value) is shown as the label on each legend.

Comment: Do you want a separate legend for each facet? If not, it seems you could use dplyr::case_when to change the sizes upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
sfc %>%
  group_by(analyte) %>%
  mutate(value_scaled = value / max(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(size = value_scaled)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 5)) +
  facet_wrap(~analyte)
```

[image]

Comment: Something along those lines would answer the question as I first asked it. However, I was hoping for a different scale for each facet with the true value of the analyte given by the scale labels, but the size of the dot showing the relationship of the true value to the guideline value.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to get separate legends per facet. Probably simpler to make separate plots and use `patchwork` to combine.